# List of commercial banks by country in Europe

Tags: data-request, banking

How do I find a list of all operating commercial banks by country?

I am only interested in commercial banks. Not building societies nor community banks.

I expected that that list should be made available on [EuroStat](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat)
or from [consolidated banking data by ECB](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money/consolidated/html/index.en.html)
but it's not as they don't differentiate between commercial banks and other credit institutions.

For example, for UK at some point in that past, that list would look like [this](https://pastebin.com/y5Y9xh2f).

Answer (score 2):

I think i have answers for your question.

In "thebanks.eu" you can find banks list by country and there is a filter so you can find commercial banks in Europe. 
https://thebanks.eu/banks-by-country

There is an other answer for your question; "stockopedia.com". This time you can find banks list and data. But there is no filter so you can not find only commercial banks and this service isn't free.

https://www.stockopedia.com/sectors/banking-services-551010//